# How can I convert seconds to miniutes and seconds using filters in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert the seconds to minutes and seconds using angular js filters can any body help me .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RAiq57LPtWe9vtTVsP1w?p=preview)

```
app.filter('toMinSec', function(){
  return function(input){
    var minutes = parseInt(input/60, 10);
    var seconds = input%60;

    return minutes+' minutes'+(seconds ? ' and '+seconds+' seconds' : '');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple filter for your requirement is as shown below.. you just need to fetch minutes with `/60` and seconds using `%60`. Providing an extra check for bad inputs.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('secondsToMinute', function(){

 return function(timeInSeconds){
 
  if(isNaN(timeInSeconds)){
   return 'bad time. Enter time in seconds';
  }else{
   var minuteValue = parseInt(timeInSeconds/60);
   var secondsValue = timeInSeconds%60;
  }
  
  return minuteValue + 'min, ' + secondsValue + 'sec';
 
 }

});

app.controller('timeController', function($scope){
   $scope.goodTime = 1254;
   $scope.badTime = "some time";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="timeController">

  <div> Good Time is --> {{goodTime | secondsToMinute}}</div>
  
  <div> Bad Time is -->  {{badTime | secondsToMinute}}</div>
  
</div>
```